# Put my Windows 8 to start in safe mode now it wont start at all

Tags: windows-8, safe-mode

I've put my W8 Pro x64 to start in safe mode via msconfig so that I could delete a bunch of locked files but now it won't start at all. The W8 boot screen will come up but then the screen will go dark and never actually boot. Help?

Comment: Sounds like you deleted critical files you should not have to boot to safe mode to delete files.  Can you still boot into safe mode?

Comment: I was just deleting some music and videos that I don't even know why were locked by explorer.exe in the first place. Now I can't even log into Windows to put it to boot up in normal mode again. The screen is just black. Weird thing: Num Lock light on keyboard won't go off. if I hit Num Lock, the light goes off for a couple of seconds then turns back on

Comment: What else did you change in `msconfig`?

Comment: @Tom - I have never known explorer.exe to open and lock files.  Windows Explorer is file manager, it shouldn't lock any files, you sure that was the process keeping the files from being deleted?

Comment: Alex, I've changed selected to boot on safe mode under the "boot" tab. Ramhound, LockHunter is a program that tells you which process is locking your file or folder and it pointed to explorer.exe in this case.